# Weird problems with SSH on remote server

Tags: ssh

I am able to login to my virtual server as root as well as username `naveed` through password-less SSH. I have to run Hadoop on it, for that purpose I have created private and public keys in my remote ssh directory and also added public key to `authorized_keys` file.
But when I do `ssh comquest` it asks for password. Comquest is hostname of my remote server.

Below are my permissions info:

```
naveed@comquest:~$ stat -c "%a %n" ~/.ssh
755 /home/naveed/.ssh
naveed@comquest:~$ stat -c "%a %n" ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
644 /home/naveed/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Below is the error I got with `naveed@comquest:$ ssh -vvv comquest`

```
naveed@comquest:/usr/local/hadoop$ ssh -vvv comquest
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "comquest" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to comquest [173.82.212.48] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/naveed/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/naveed/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/naveed/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/naveed/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/naveed/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/naveed/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/naveed/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/naveed/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to comquest:22 as 'naveed'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/naveed/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/naveed/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from comquest
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:jad0RkXVMVxVyKD+9eY7abnSnUEz31nn+IMCfVUk7CA
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/naveed/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/naveed/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from comquest
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/naveed/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/naveed/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 173.82.212.48
debug1: Host 'comquest' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/naveed/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/naveed/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/naveed/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/naveed/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/naveed/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 53
debug3: input_userauth_banner
 CloudCone LLC
 ----------------------------------------------- 
 KVM Cloud Server           Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
 ----------------------------------------------- 
 Service Status             status.cloudcone.com
 Client Area & Help Desk    app.cloudcone.com
 FAQs and Documentation     help.cloudcone.com

 -- NOTICE ---------------------------------------------------------------
 This computer system is for authorized users only. Individuals using this                                    
 system without authority or in excess of their authority are subject to                                      
 having all their activities on this system monitored and recorded or                                         
 examined by any authorized person, including law enforcement, as system                                      
 personnel deem appropriate. In the course of monitoring individuals                                          
 improperly using the system or in the course of system maintenance, the                                      
 activities of authorized users may also be monitored and recorded. Any                                       
 material so recorded may be disclosed as appropriate. Anyone using this                                      
 system consents to these terms.
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/naveed/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/naveed/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/naveed/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/naveed/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/naveed/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/naveed/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/naveed/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/naveed/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
naveed@comquest's password:
```

Below are the contents of my remote ~/.ssh folder:

```
naveed@comquest:~$ ls ~/.ssh
authorized_keys  known_hosts  local  local.pub
```

local and local.pub are keys generated by `naveed@comquest` to access `comquest`. local.pub is added to authorized_keys.

Comment: Hint: `id_rsa: No such file or directory`... You need this file. Regenerate your SSH key pairs on the server

Answer (score 0):

Your private key is in a file named `local`, but that's not a name that `ssh` looks for (by default).  Your `ssh -vvv` output shows that it's only looking for the default key filenames, such as `id_rsa` and `id_dsa`.

Either rename your `local` and `local.pub` files to match the expected naming convention (e.g. `id_rsa` or whatever, depending on what type of key it is), or add `-o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/local` to your `ssh` command line.

Comment: But I have named by private key (on my laptop) in a similar manner, remote server has no issues then. Anyway I removed the `local` keys and created new pair with `id_rsa` name and its working now.

Comment: Maybe your laptop has an `IdentityFile` option in `~/.ssh/config` that tells it to look for `local`.  But it's usually simpler to just stick to the default naming convention for SSH key files.